# How to design a UI for user to declare injuries?

Tags: interface, error-prevention, health

I was discussing with a friend about a healthcare application he is working on and he tell me about a UI his team was working on.

#### Users' task

The application is used by independent/self-employed workers (in France) and should help them declare on which part and **side** an injury took place.

#### Goal

The interface should help prevent declaration errors.
As his question was *"should we display the body from front or back view?"* as the teammates had different opinions on which side was right/left?

#### Question

Should he go for a mirror image or a 'shadow projection' ?

Answer (score 4):

If I were you I would let the user have a little "flip-toggle" that allows them to switch between both sides of the person. In this type of application being able to show both sides may be a necessity. If the user reports an injury directly in the center how would you know if its a sternum or spinal injury?

To differentiate sides (even if you dont allow flipping) label the hands to avoid confusion, then if you allow flipping draw a face and supply a front/back label. Like this:
[image]

Comment: I would add that there is a possibility that the reported injuries may have occurred on the back or the front so allowing the user to flip is more likely to be a necessity.